# How to correctly implement jQuery menu function into Wordpress using get_template_directory_uri() for

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, menu

Having been building Wordpress sites exclusively using themes, I have become frustrated by the huge bloat themed sites include.  I have taken the plunge and am trying to build out my first site using the Underscores framework.

I'm currently having trouble implementing some jQuery menu slider into a Wordpress site : www.AtlanticWebsites.co.uk

I would like to implement some jQuery sourced from bigSlide.js

http://ascott1.github.io/bigSlide.js/#how

**Steps I have taken:**

Uploaded bigSlide.js file into js.folder/directory

This contains all code from following:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ascott1/bigSlide.js/master/dist/bigSlide.min.js

**Inserted following code into functions.php file:**

```
function atlanticwebsites_init_js_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script('big_Slide', get_template_directory_uri() .
'/js/bigSlide.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'atlanticwebsites_init_js_scripts' );
```

**Inserted following code into header.php file:**

```
<a href="#menu" class="menu-link">&#9776;</a>

    <nav id="menu" class="panel" role="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Optimisation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Google Adwords</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Responsive Design</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Our Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

<script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">   
</script>
<script src="jquery.big-slide.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu-link').bigSlide();
    });
</script>
```

**I've inserted following code into style.css**

```
.panel {
    position: fixed;
    left: -15.625em; /*left or right and the width of your navigation     panel*/
    width: 15.625em; /*should match the above value*/
}

.wrap {
    position: relative;
}
```

The menu tab shows, but doesn't work. 
Questions could someone check what's missing?
I suspect I've incorrectly placed code in either

function.php or header.php
or omitted code?

Also, should I strip out the existing code relating to 'navigation' which was pre-populated with Underscores Framework basic install?

Many Thanks

Comment: In debug mod of your browser you can see if there are the 404 error's. Also Why you defined <script src="jquery.big-slide.js"></script> ? I think you should define more specific related path

Comment: If you're enqueueing your scripts, and assuming you're using [`wp_head()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) in your head template file, there is no need to hard-code `jquery.big-slide.js` like you have in header.php. In addition I find header.php problematic. That's not where you want to place your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Valeriy

According to your enqueue_scripts function the bigslide.js resides in js folder but in your  header.php file you have included it without the js folder so you may wanna check that.

Comment: Thanks for response guys.  @DhavalChheda have added following code to header.php   

<script src='/js.big-slide.js'></script>                                                                 However I still can't seem to get it to work.  Any help appreciated

Comment: you have the slashes incorrect..it should be js/file_name.js